# using max query with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new with mongoose and still trying to understand how make correct queries

I have 2 simple Models

**User** :

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
name: String,
age: Number,
movies:[{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'movie'
}]
}, { collection: 'USER_COLLEC' });
```

**Movie** :

```
 const MovieSchema = new Schema({
    title:String , 
    duration: Number
}, { collection: 'MOVIE_COLLEC' });
```

What I want is **the user with le longest movie** ( highest duration )

For now I got that :

```
db.getCollection('USER_COLLEC') .
aggregate([
{ "$unwind": "$movies" } ,
{ $lookup:
    {from: "MOVIE_COLLEC",
    localField: "movies",
    foreignField: "_id",
    as: "movieContent"},
 } ,
 { $unwind: "$movieContent" },
 { $group: 
    { maxDuration: { $max: "$movieContent.duration" }, 
    }
  }
])
```

But it will only find the max duration with no user attached to it...
And indeed I only ask for the max duration on my query, but after the lookup I lose my user :(

How can I can keep it, or retrieve my user data ?

If you have any idea, I am completely stuck...

Thanks guys !

Comment: I think you're going to need to do an aggregation. Don't have time right now to work it out but you can read the docs here, https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Jason ! I am checking it right now !

Comment: Ok, I am now closer I have edit my post, I have the max duration but I have lost the user in the same time when I used the lookup clause.

Comment: Why not just get the movie with max duration, then get the user with that movie? Does that fulfill your need?

Comment: I thought about that, but the movie with the longest duration is not necessarily attached to a user . ( Not all movies are used )

Comment: But one movie could also be assigned to multiple users, what do you want to do in that case? Or you just want to return first user?

Comment: @Topsy, check the update in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to find the solution, the $group was not the solution

```
db.getCollection('USER_COLLEC') .
aggregate([
{ "$unwind": "$movies" } ,
{ $lookup:
    {from: "MOVIE_COLLEC",
    localField: "movies",
    foreignField: "_id",
    as: "movieContent"},
 } ,
{ $unwind: "$movieContent" },
 {$sort: {"movieContent.duration":-1}},
 { $project: {  "user":"$name","duration" : "$movieContent.duration"}  }  ,
 { $limit : 1 }
```

Which gives me something like :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59d2f64dded1c008192f7e73"),
    "user" : "Michael",
    "duration" : 96
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use $push to get the movie object as well.

```
db.getCollection('USER_COLLEC') .
aggregate([
{ "$unwind": "$movies" } ,
{ $lookup:
    {from: "MOVIE_COLLEC",
    localField: "movies",
    foreignField: "_id",
    as: "movieContent"},
 } ,
 { $unwind: "$movieContent" },
 { $group: 
    { _id: { $max: "$movieContent.duration" }, 
    "movie": {
            "$push": "movieContent"
        }
    }
  }
])
```

After this, just get search for the Movie's _id in the user's movies array

```
UserSchema.find({movies:{$in:movieContent[0]._id}});
```

OR, instead of `$push` you can also use `$first`

```
{ $first: "$movieContent" }
```

Then you won't get it in an array.

**Update:**

Instead of `{$push: $movieContent}` or`{$first: $movieContent}`, you could just push `$$ROOT`:
`{$push: $$ROOT}` or `{$first: $$ROOT}`
and then you'll get the entire object. You don't need to fire another query to get the user.

Comment: I can't wait to test this at home , thanks Dushyant, I'll let you know, thanks !

Comment: Finally your solution keep returning multiple users and moreover they  all have redundancy of movie in their responses, BUT it made me understand how to find the solution haha :)

Comment: Yes, probably because I just extended your code of grouping and populating. I had not tested it :) Glad to be of help